# Is there a java8 standard library class that means "possibly with exception" in the same way as java.util.Optional means "possibly null"?

Tags: java

I have classes called say `CalculationOutcome` and `FileHashOutcome`. Their constructors have `(ActualResult, Throwable)` arguments, and at the end of a chain of `CompletionStage`s I have `handle(XxxOutcome::new)`.

It might make intentions clearer and save some boilerplate if I could write say `PossiblyWithError<FileHash>`.

Edit: People asking for example code...

```java
class FileHashOutcome {
  private final String hash;
  private final Throwable throwable;
  FileHashOutcome(String hash, Throwable throwable){
    // Usual assignments
  }
}

CompletionStage<FileHashOutcome> future =
   SomeExternalLibrary.calculateHash(file) 
   // ...It's a CompletionStage<String> at this stage...
   .handle(FileHashOutcome::new);

// Then I pass `future` to a service that 
// will execute it and pass back the result asynchronously
```

To be specific, it's within an Akka actor, and I'm asking the infrastructure to [pipe](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/pattern/Patterns.html#pipe(java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage,scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)) the result back into the actor as a message.

Edit: suggestions that `CompletableFuture` might do the job... Yes, good point, it represents exactly what needs to be represented. And it's a bit of a code smell to implement your own rough-and-ready future then wrap it in the java8 future.

There are some hoops to jump through depending on whether you have access to the "envelope" of the future. If you're inside a `thenApply` then you're "inside" the envelope and you don't know it. And the Akka infrastructure "throws away" the envelope and only returns the result (and it returns nothing if there was an exception, which is one of the main reasons why I wanted to catch and wrap that exception at the end of the `CompletionStage` chain). Of course, since I created the CompletionStage, I could hold onto it in a member variable until the infrastructure nudged me that it had completed.

Comment: It's not in the standard library, but the usual name for this class is `Try`.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Show some code, please.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Do you want to pass this thing as an argument instead of the Throwable? If so, just have two constructors, one which doesn't take a throwable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @marstran, the usual name for this class is **Try**.

Scala has such a class in its standard library: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html

The same can be done in Java, but it is not a part of the standard library: https://dzone.com/articles/why-try-better-exception-handling-in-java-with-try

Comment: This seems pretty similar to a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).  Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're not, @VGR, `CompletableFuture` does all that, and in better, indeed.

Comment: Hey @VGR, does what you're saying deserve to be another answer to this question? - could even end up the chosen answer I guess.